# delete a Object from an Array stored in localStorage on a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have stored certain information in localStorage like-

```
$localStorage.recent = [{'id':1,'name':'abc','is_availbale':1},{'id':2,'name':'xyz','is_availbale':1},{'id':3,'name':'pqrs','is_availbale':0}];
```

having another array which is only having id's of certain people like(array_second can have only those id's which are already there in 
$localStorage.recent)-

```
array_second=['3'];
```

I want to delete those entries from $localStorage.recent which are corresponding to the id's in array_second. Expected output to be-

```
$localStorage.recent = [{'id':1,'name':'abc','is_availbale':1},{'id':2,'name':'xyz','is_availbale':1}];
```

Comment: You want a solution with Angularjs ?

Comment: `$localStroage.recent = $localstroage.recent.filter(...` more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

You're just handling a standard array. The ngstorage library doesn't give you any additional functionality here.

For example:

```
$localStorage.recent = $localStorage.recent.filter((person) => {
    return second_array.indexOf(person.id) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may useful to you, written in javascript

```
var fullArr =[{'id':1,'name':'abc','is_availbale':1{'id':2,'name':'xyz','is_availbale':1},{'id':3,'name':'pqrs','is_availbale':0}];

     var toDelArr = [1];
     for(var i=0;i<fullArr.length;i++){
          if(toDelArr[0] == fullArr[i].id){ 
          fullArr.splice(i, 1); 
          } 
     }
```